# Position [1] in my Array won't Register

Tags: java, arrays, swing, loops, while-loop

I am trying to output the alphabet with a space key and . into a virtual keyboard using a loop to create the buttons. However, the "w" button wont display and I have no idea why. All other buttons will show.

An extract of my Code is shown below.

```
String[] chars =
{"q","w","e","r","t","y","u","i","o","p","a","s","d","f","g","h","j","k","l",".","z","x","c","v","b","n","m"," "};

while (x<28)
            {
                JButton button = new JButton(chars[z]);
                pane.add(button, gBC);
                button.addActionListener(this);
                button.setActionCommand(chars[z]);
                gBC.gridx = z%10;
                gBC.gridy = z/10;
                x ++;
                z ++;
            }

            JButton space = new JButton();
            gBC.gridx = 0;
            gBC.gridy = 4;
            gBC.gridwidth = 10;
            pane.add(space, gBC);
```

Many Thanks in advance!

Comment: you are initializing `x=0` and `z=0` i´d guess?

Comment: Yes I do, I just didnt want to copy my whole code in here.

Comment: @Abdelhak `GridBagConstraints` i´d guess..

Comment: @Abdelhak That is correct, would it help if I uploaded more code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from what i did test locally, you should move.

```
gBC.gridx = z%10;
gBC.gridy = z/10;
```

to the start of the loop. This gave me the desired result.
You are allways one off with the positioning.
You basicly calculate the positioning for the next element with the values from the previous one.

```
while (x < 28) {
    gBC.gridx = z % 10;
    gBC.gridy = z / 10;
    JButton button = new JButton(chars[z]);
    pane.add(button, gBC);
    button.addActionListener(this);
    button.setActionCommand(chars[z]);
    x++;
    z++;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, god damn, this website is amazing!